# How can prevent writes to a Postgres schema for a period of time?

Tags: postgresql, schema, pg-dump

I am moving a schema from one server to another using pg_dump + pg_restore + drop schema cascade. I need to know that no applications are writing to it (or at least that the writes will fail) during this process to avoid losing data.

At the moment I am renaming the schema before starting the dump. Is that sufficient to prevent writes? What if a large batch insert is busy when I rename the schema? Will that still complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `REVOKE` access from that schema, but I am affraid the application will have some unwanted effects. PostgreSQL has fine tuned permission administration. And later you can `GRANT` access to that schema.

Comment: Can I do that (and restore access) as a 'normal' user?

Comment: You can if you are owner of the schema (creator), otherwise you need to be super user or admin.